# Facebook GraphAPI, Delete user invitation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using PHP and FacebookAPI, all is almost ok except for a strange error.
I tried to find solution on facebook developers site and google but with no luck.
This is the scenario:

- Event 368441533230244 is created
- User 100004484143351 is invited to the event 368441533230244

Now I want to remove the user from the event.
According to Facebook API docs, my APP own the permissions

- rsvp_event
- user_event
- friend_event

And many others :)

Now calling the api:

```
$FB->api("368441533230244/invited/100004484143351", 'DELETE');
```

I obtain an Exception with the following details:

```
["result":protected] => array(1) {
    ["error"] => array(3) {
    ["message"] => string(8) "(#1002) "
    ["type"] => string(14) "OAuthException"
    ["code"] => int(1002)
}
```

I was unable to find something about Error Code 1002, and as you can see there is no error description.

Any idea? :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you make the call via the API, do you know if the user on whose behalf you are acting is an admin. It's documented here under the Delete section - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: The user is the same that created the event. I cover all the conditions into the api/event delete section, any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be a side effect of the [Events Timezone migration](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/).

Events created using a web browser at facebook.com will behave like the migration is enabled.  But your app probably has the Events Timezone migration *disabled*.  This is causing a mismatch and the issue.

So do this: Keep the Events Timezone migration disabled in your app and create events using the Graph API instead of the web-ui/browser. This will ensure events are created and modified with the same migration setting.

You can check your app's migrations settings in the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) > Advanced > Migrations.

If you are using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to create events, make sure you select your App from the dropdown list "Application", at the top.

Comment: The event is created and managed through the api, Not web interface at all

Comment: I would retry with the "Events Timezone" migration **enabled**.

Comment: Done, no changes. Same Issue :(